# How does -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am currently working under the assumption that `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does not utilize threading, but schedules an event to fire at a later date on the current thread.  Is this correct?

More, specifically:

```
- (void) methodCalledByButtonClick {
  for (id obj in array) {
    [self doSomethingWithObj:obj];
  }
}

static BOOL isBad = NO;
- (void) doSomethingWithObj:(id)obj {
  if (isBad) {
    return;
  }
  if ([obj isBad]) {
    isBad = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(resetIsBad) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    return;
  }
  //Do something with obj
}

- (void) resetIsBad {
  isBad = NO;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that `-resetIsBad` will not be called until after `-methodCalledByButtonClick` returns, assuming we are running on the main thread, even if `-methodCalledByButtonClick` takes an arbitrarily long time to complete?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:):

> Invokes a method of the receiver on
>   the **current thread** using the default
>   mode after a delay.

The discussion goes further:

> This method sets up a timer to perform
>   the aSelector message on the current
>   thread’s run loop. The timer is
>   configured to run in the default mode
>   (NSDefaultRunLoopMode). When the timer
>   fires, the thread attempts to dequeue
>   the message from the run loop and
>   perform the selector. It succeeds if
>   the run loop is running and in the
>   default mode; otherwise, the timer
>   waits until the run loop is in the
>   default mode.

From this we can answer your second question. **Yes, it's guaranteed**, even with a shorter delay since the current thread is busy executing when `performSelector` is called. When the thread returns to the run loop and dequeues the selector, you'll have returned from your `methodCalledByButtonClick`.

Answer (score 12):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` schedules a timer on the same thread to call the selector after the passed delay. If you sign up for the default run mode (i.e. don't use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:`), I believe it is guaranteed to wait until the next pass through the run loop, so everything on the stack will complete first.

Even if you call with a delay of 0, it will wait until the next loop, and behave as you want here. For more info refer to [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:).

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a delay of 0 will still not cause it to run immediately?  The docs say "not necessarily" but that's different than "necessarily not", so I'm curious

Comment: It's always worked that way in my experience, but good point. I don't know if it is guaranteed.

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me   [self performSelector:@selector(showLoginScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

Comment: FYI blocks do not wait until the next pass through the run loop.