# XCode Storyboard How to access all view controllers inside the storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

In a Single View Application, Inside the storyboard if I've multiple view controllers with different classes assigned to them,

How can I access all of them inside AppDelegate while still know what kind (Class) of ViewController is this?

for instance root view controller I can access

```
BlackTimer *vc = (BlackTimer *)_window.rootViewController;
```

how about the other sibling view controllers?

Comment: Answer is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate

Answer (score 1):

Create iVar of your sibling UIViewControllers inside your app delegate and later whenever you invoke a view controller you alloc init the ivar which is inside app delegate. You can get reference to app delegate from anywhere by using

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Sorry it's still not clear to me, inside AppDelegate. I wanna access all the view controllers (from storybaord)