# Can I get the same viewcontroller object from storyboard and from code?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have already referred [Storyboard - refer to ViewController in AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate).

I want to ask whether it's the same viewcontroller obj as we can see in storyboard. if we code like:

```
    FirstViewController* fvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"];
    NSLog(@"fvc=%@", fvc);
    [fvc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"go2next" sender:fvc];
```

as I tested, it is not the same as:

```
    NSLog(@"self=%@", self);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"go2next" sender:self];
```

From log, I can see they are not the same objs. How can I get the same view controller obj from storyboard by code?

I created two viewcontroller named(FirstViewController, SecondController) in storyboard, and add a segue between the two. I tried to use performSegueWithIdentifier to transfer to the the second page. [self performSegueWithIdentifier]works, while [fvc performSegueWithIdentifier]doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem at last. if I add the following lines in AppDelegate.m

```
FirstViewController* fvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"];
self.window.rootViewController = fvc;
NSLog(@"fvc=%@", fvc);
[fvc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"go2next" sender:fvc];
```

It worked the same as:

```
NSLog(@"self=%@", self);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"go2next" sender:self];
```