# How to deal with storyboard instead of xib file in such case?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6, appdelegate

I have an example where I have animation when the app starts. At the start an image is displayed, then moves from right to left, then disappears. Below is the code I have.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewwController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewwController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    //add the image to the forefront...
    UIImageView *splashImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [splashImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
    [self.window addSubview:splashImage];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashImage];


    //set an anchor point on the image view so it opens from the left
    splashImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

    //reset the image view frame
    splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    //animate the open
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.6
                        options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut) 
                     animations:^{

                         splashImage.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, -M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         //remove that imageview from the view
                         [splashImage removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

    return YES;

}
```

What I want is to do this using a storyboard, so I changed the code as below.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
MyBookViewController *myNew = [[MyBookViewController alloc] init];
self.myBookViewController = myNew;
self.window.rootViewController = self.myBookViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

However I don't see my viewcontroller (MyBookViewController). I only see the image moving from right to left, then a black screen.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: why downvote? what is wrong in this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did it myself with help of [`this SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate).

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];
MyBook001ViewController *controller = (MyBook001ViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"firstStory"];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I think since the addition of storyboards there is more of a trend to create less code. That said, I would have declared the `Main storyboard file base name` (aka UIMainStoryboardFile) in your Info.plist file for the target you're working with. Then I would have created a class linked to a view (your splash screen) to animate out of view and push a new view to the user. Perhaps you'll like this implementation better? Just an option...

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because of you are allocating new MyBookViewController. instead it you have to give reference of storyboard, on which you have your UI design for MyBookViewController,  like this

```
MyBookViewController *myNew=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyBookViewController"];
```

be sure for ViewController identifier

UPdate1:

try with

```
MyBookViewController *myNew=[self.window.rootViewController];
```

Comment: I tried this also. but i get error as `property storyboard not found on object of type MyBookAppDelegate.m`

Comment: still same black screen when I had `MyBookViewController *myNew=self.window.rootViewController;`

Comment: @user1996238;create one new viewcontroller & in Viewdidload add your code with storyboard reference

Comment: but how can i reach to new viewcontroller?

Comment: @user1996238:assign that new viewController to rootviewController