# How to push Storyboard from loginviewcontroller which is an xib

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xib

I am having Loginview controller,I have created it with Xib and i want to push mainstoryboard on clicking loginbutton.

```
LoginViewController *lObjloginview = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *lObjtempview = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lObjloginview];
self.window.rootViewController = lObjtempview;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This will add loginview from xib.but after pressing loginbutton I want to load storyboard.Can anyone help me in pushing mainstoryboard which has tabbar controller inside mainstoryboard to link xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the initial view controller from the storyboard and present it

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * initialVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = initialVC;
```

If you know a priori the class you're instantiating

```
UITabBarController * initialVC = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: In this If I want to set some properties of Second tabbar controller in storyboard then how will I have do that??

Comment: you can instantiate any view controller from the storyboard using `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Whatever"]`. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate

Comment: How to access the [initialVC objectAtIndex:1] so that i want to set some properties.

Comment: Here initialVC is a tabbarcontroller for me

Comment: Just cast it to a `UITabBarController`, see my updated answer