# Xcode 5 Storyboard - presentViewController not presenting my existing Viewcontroller and giving black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have two view controller named ViewController and SecondViewController. From the first view controller i m trying to call my SecondViewController after 5 second. but it will giving me black screen instead of my expected view.

Here is my view controller code,

```
`

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self performSelector:@selector(loadingNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];

}

-(void)loadingNextView{
    SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    SVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end`
```

Please suggest. If i used button for navigation then its work but my needs is to call automatically on timer.

Comment: `SecondViewController ` is in storyboard?

Comment: yes it is in storyboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storyboard - refer to ViewController in AppDelegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate)

Answer (score 1):

If your `SecondViewController` is in storyboard instead of `alloc init` you have use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
```

Dont forget to give the **identifier** for the controller in the storyboard. So the method will be

```
-(void)loadingNextView{
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    SVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the controller exact from the storyboard.

```
- (void)loadingNetView
{
    UIStoryboard storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NSString *identifier = @"SecondController"; // you need to set identifier in storyboard
    SecondViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

Comment: where this i need to write in my Viewconroller.m file.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard then you cannot initialise the controller with the nib Method "initWithNibName" basically searches for an Xib file, which you do not have as you are using a storyboard, better initialise it in the following way ..

```
 -(void)callNextView{

    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryBoarddName" bundle:nil];

    yourViewController *VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
   [self presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: but it giving me error for storyboard name not found. Where i have to set / check story board name?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the storyboard, you can simply init the new controller like this

```
SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
[SVC setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[self presentViewController: SVC animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: My issue resolved thanks i just do with correct storyboard name

Comment: -(void)loadingNextView{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    
    NSString *identifier = @"SecondViewController";
    
    SecondViewController *SVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    
    //[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}