# iOS: Check if user is already logged in using Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I have started working on an iOS app on Xcode using Swift and storyboards. I have a requirement where on click of a button I will show a user's Facebook profile info on the screen (only if user is signed in using Facebook), but if he is not signed in it will automatically go to login screen and on successful login again the profile view will be shown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using the Facebook Login SDK, call

```
FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

It will be not nil if the user is logged in.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#token

Comment: They did ask for Swift, which would be `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()`.

Comment: Thanks for this information. However, I have another doubt that now when started app another time how can I skip the login page to directly go to profile page. I am sure this is something to do with secure but I am a bit confused

Comment: You'd need to call that function in your AppDelegate and choose which ViewController to go to based on that

Comment: Ok, so does this approach of setting view controller from AppDelegate works even when I am using storyboard to build my app.

Comment: Yes but rather than letting the app use the Storyboard specified in your Info.plist, you must instantiate it yourself. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26757245/78496

You will have to give your ViewControllers identifiers if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8186721/78496

Comment: For me it doesn't return nil however when I take that token and validate it this is what I get

Facebook::AuthenticationError: type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 458, message: Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application

Comment: changed to **AccessToken.current**

Answer (score 6):

With latest Facebook SDK, You can check like this :

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {
    // logged in
}
else {
    // not logged in 
}
```

They recently changed from `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` to `FBSDKAccessToken.current()`

Comment: it should not work.
As FBSDKAccessToken.current() is returning non-nil value.
check the return type. its  FBSDKAccessToken! which guarantees that this could never be nil.
I don't know how its working, but its working.

Comment: I think following should be the code...

if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil){
            // logged in
        }else{
            // not logged in
        }

Answer (score 3):

in sdk for swift 5 use the next portion of code:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

if AccessToken.isCurrentAccessTokenActive {
    print("your session is active")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more convenient and standard code in swift you can use this following code snippet. BTW I am using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1.

```
if let loggedInUsingFBTokenCheck = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken(){
     //User is already logged-in. Please do your additional code/task.
}else{
    //User is not logged-in. Allow the user for login using FB.
}
```

If you want to load specific viewController during app launch based on login check you can place this code inside your project's `AppDelegate` and check inside -

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
//Check here for login
}
```

Thank You.