# How to call the func in ViewController from appdelegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, func

I am trying to call the function in `ViewController` from `appdelegate` in Swift?

In `Appdelegate.swift`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var first: FirstViewController!

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {

        FirstViewController.fileurl(url)
        first.fileurl(url)
        return true
    }
}
```

In `FirstViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var externalFile: NSURL!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func fileurl(url: NSURL){
        externalFile = url
        println("externalFile = \(externalFile)")
}
}
```

In `Appdelegate.swift` , I call the `FirstViewController.fileurl()` and also try to call `first.fileurl()`.

When I call `FirstViewController.fileurl(url)` , it show **Cannot invoke 'fileurl' with an argument list of type '(NSURL)'**.

When I call `first.fileurl(url)` , it crash and the error log is **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**.

Did I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the logs did you see any variable name for which this error is showing up? It looks like that the method is being called but the `url` parameter has a nil value, and its crashing due to force unwrap

Comment: is `FirstViewController` is a view controller that is in navigation stack or it is the visible controller?

Comment: @developer I have print the `url` , it is not nil.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr it is the visible controller!

Comment: @Martin try printing your `first` object, I guess its `nil`

Comment: @Martin are you using navigationcontroller? and does that the root view controller?

Comment: @developer Yes...first is nil...

Answer (score 2):

It's your UIViewController called `first` that is not initialized. If this done in another place e.g. in storyboard during loading of your app, you only need to assign the rootviewcontroller to your variable. One way of doing this is:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var first: COBezierDemoViewController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        if let firstViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? COBezierDemoViewController {
            self.first = firstViewController
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        first?.fileurl(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the way it worked for me immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `first` object is `nil` you should first allocate a **new object** by using the below code :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {

        let first = FirstViewController()
        first.fileurl(url)
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your storyboard. Give identifier to your ViewController using storyboard.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<Controller ID>") as FirstViewController
vc.fileurl(url)
```

Comment: Hi , I have try. But it show  'AppDelegate.Type' does not have a member named 'mainStoryboard'

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186375/storyboard-refer-to-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate