# Storyboard doesn't push a view when i use "perform segue with identifier " Method

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

I am using storyboard for normal transition between views where normally i use "performsegue with identifier".
But there is one view controller whom i push using segues(with correct identifiers),the class associated with that controlled gets called but the story board doesn't load the view.
There is this one warning i get

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ParsingViewController: 0xa294940>.
```

Also when i print the navigation controller array it shows my previous view getting called twice(i.e. ParsingViewController)

```
Navigation array (
"<LoginController4: 0x8d86830>",
"<ParsingViewController: 0x8c9e760>",
"<ParsingViewController: 0xa294940>",
"<UIViewController: 0x8ec31f0>"
```

)

I am sitting with this issue for hours, but am not able to push the view controller using segue.

Answer (score 0):

Google that message and you will see lots of information on the topic. Here is one that may help: [Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x197870>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886096/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-uitabbarcontroller-0x)