# Unbalance Calls Warning on Modal Present then Navigation Pop to Root in Completion

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Take the below code (called from any given view controller in a navigation stack).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = MyViewController()
    present(vc, animated: true) {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly well and everything behaves as expected. However, I get the following warning.

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyApp.MyViewController: 0x1044276d0>.
```

So, given the warning printed, is there a better way to have a user be at the root of a navigation stack when they dismiss a modal view controller presented from any given view controller in the navigation stack?

Comment: you can try delegate. From ViewDidAppear method of view controller being presented

Comment: where you called this `let vc = MyViewController()` in page load or else

Comment: Check this answer and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886348/1433612 I think the theory 1 may be applicable for you.

Comment: @anthonydito Did you solve these unbalanced calls?