# PerformSelector with Delay 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic-dispatch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922517/how-does-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay-work)

I often use this code to let the UI finish its business before calling a long-running method:

```
[obj performSelector:@selector(go) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

But **what does it do?**

My personal interpretation has always been that the `go` method is called on the next run loop, but surely that's not even right.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922583/191794

Comment: Thanks Tom, that works. Should I remove the question (delete)?

Comment: @Nate: They did? WTF. That was incredibly helpful when knowing whether the asker was unlikely to mark anything as answered.

Comment: I'd kind of prefer that it get closed as a dupe, @Nate, because it offers different keywording than the other question. Otherwise i'd just delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Calling it with delay `0` will indeed invoke this method on the next pass through the runloop.

IIRC, what it does is set up a struct that represents the target and action, and attach a `CFRunLoopSource` to the runloop that, when triggered, will invoke the action on the target. It then signals the runloop to tell it that it has a ready source. This means that the next time the runloop processes its sources (i.e. the next pass through the runloop), it will perform your delayed selector.